# Socket.SendAsync is not sending in-order on Mono/Linux

Tags: c#, linux, sockets, mono, sendasync

There is a a single-threaded server using .NET Socket with TCP protocol, and `Socket.Pool()`, `Socket.Select()`, `Socket.Receive()`.

To send, I used:

```
public void SendPacket(int clientid, byte[] packet)
{
    clients[clientid].socket.Send(packet);
}
```

But it was very slow when sending a lot of data to one client (halting the whole main thread), so I replaced it with this:

```
public void SendPacket(int clientid, byte[] packet)
{
    using (SocketAsyncEventArgs e = new SocketAsyncEventArgs())
    {
        e.SetBuffer(packet, 0, packet.Length);
        clients[clientid].socket.SendAsync(e);
    }
}
```

It works fine on Windows with .NET (I don't know if it's perfect), but on Linux with Mono, packets are either dropped or reordered (I don't know). Reverting to slow version with Socket.Send() works on Linux. [Source for whole server](http://manicdigger.git.sourceforge.net/git/gitweb.cgi?p=manicdigger/manicdigger;a=blob;f=GameModeFortress/Server.cs;hb=HEAD).

How to write non-blocking SendPacket() function that works on Linux?

Answer (score 1):

I'm going to take a guess that it has to do with your `using` statement and your `SendAsync` call. Perhaps `e` falls out of scope and is being disposed while `SendAsync` is still processing the buffer. But then this might throw an exception. I am really just taking a guess. Try removing the `using` statement and see what happens.

Comment: `using` was added because there was an OutOfMemoryException without it.

Answer (score 0):

I would say by not abusing the async method. YOu will find nowhere a documentation stating that this acutally is forced to maintain order. it queues iem for a scheuler which get distributed to threads, and by ignoring that the oder is not maintained per documentation you open yourself up to implementation details.

The best possibly is to:

- Have a queue per socket.
- When you write dasta into this queue, and there is no worker thread, start a work item (ThreadPool) to process the thread.

This way you have separate distinct queues that maintain order. Only one thread will ever process one queue / socket.

Comment: A queue is unnecessary, because that is what SendAsync does internally.

Comment: Ah, no. SendAsync puts mulötipel calls to multipel threads which MAY come in the wrong oder, as the OP did experience. There is NO Quarantess 4 calls to SendAsync are processed inthe correct order.

Answer (score 0):

I got the same problem; Linux and windows react not in the same way with SendAsync. Sometimes linux truncate the data, but there is a workaround. First of all you need to use a queue. Each time you use SendAsync you have to check the callback. 
If e.Offset + e.BytesTransferred < e.Buffer.Length, you just have to e.SetBuffer(e.Offset + e.BytesTransferred, e.Buffer.Length - e.BytesTransferred - e.Offset); and call SendAsync again.

I dont know why mono-linux believe it's completed before sending all the data and it's strange but i'm sure he does.

Answer (score 0):

just like @mathieu, 10y later, I can confirm on Unity Mono+Linux complete callback is called without all bytes being sent in some cases. For me it was large packets only.